# Quiero definir una función que ingresando dos vectores (como una lista) defina si son paralelos o no

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

### Quiero definir una función que ingresando dos vectores (como una lista) defina si son paralelos o no.

Como dice el titulo: a la función le ingreso **dos vectores**, de un tamaño cualquiera, y quiero saber si son paralelos o no.
Lo que pensé es que para que sean paralelos se debe cumplir que cada componente del vector 2 es múltiplo del mismo componente del vector 1, entonces a cada componente del **vector 1** lo divido por el mismo componente del **vector 2** y guardo el resultado, todos los resultados los guardo en una lista y con `set` reduzco esa lista y con `len` veo si tiene largo 1: si es así quiere decir que todos los componentes de la lista son iguales y por ende, los vectores paralelos

```
def ortogononalidad(vector1,vector2):
resultado=[]
for i in range(len(vector1)):
    x=vector1[i]/vector2[i]
    resultado.append(x)
if len(set(resultado))==1:
    print("Los vectores son paralelos")
else:
    print("Los vectores no son paralelos")
```

El tema es cuando en el vector 2 hay componentes que son 0, lo que me lleva al error de dividir por cero. Me imagino que hay forma de plantear el tema de otra manera.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Para aclarar, ¿con paralelos quieres decir simplemente que el segundo vector es el resultado de multiplicar cada uno del los items del primero por un mismo número? Según esto consideras paralelos [1, 3, 5, 0] y  [3, 9, 15, 0]  o [0, 0, 0, 0] y  [0, 0, 0, 0] (esto cumpliría el criterio pero en realidad son el mismo vector...) pero no  [1, 3] y  [3, 12]  y tampoco [1, 3]  y  [3, 12, 24] (este caso no lo cubre tu código). ¿Es así o algo de esto no sería cierto?

Comment: Claro, yo consideraría paralelo a los vectores cuales los componentes del vector 2 se pueden obtener multiplicando por el mismo numero a cada componente del vector 1, como lo son [1, 3, 5, 0] y [3, 9, 15, 0] o [0, 0, 0, 0] y [0, 0, 0, 0], o [1,1] y [2,2] o [5,2] y [15,6].  Aunque tienes razón cuando dices que son el mismo vector... Quizás mi definición de vectores paralelos es incorrecta, pero no se me ocurre otra ya que el ejercicio me pide que ingrese los vectores en forma de tupla o lista

Answer (score 0):

Existen muchos criterios equivalentes para demostrar que dos vectores son paralelos, entre esos el que usted está teniendo en cuenta: "Dos vectores se dice que son paralelos si son proporcionales", que equivale a decir que posean la misma dirección y sentido o que la multiplicación de uno de estos vectores por un escalar (número real cualquiera) dé como resultado el otro vector. Esta condición es bastante general, ya que a diferencia de otras (Ej: En 3 dimensiones el producto vectorial es nulo), esta se le puede aplicar a cualquier conjunto de vectores independientemente de su dimensión. Como no conosco las características de los vectores que vas a ingresar, veo correcto mantener este criterio y modificar el código para filtrar los casos especiales, entre esos el caso cuando los vectores tienen componentes nulas. El código quedaría como sigue:

```
def ortogononalidad(vector1,vector2):
resultado=[]
if len(vector1)!=len(vector2):
    print("Los vectores no están definidos en el mismo espacio")
else:
    for i in range(len(vector1)):
        try:
            x=vector1[i]/vector2[i]
            resultado.append(x)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            if vector1[i]!=vector2[i]:
                resultado.append(0)
                break
    if len(set(resultado))<=1:
        if sum(resultado)<0:
            print("Los vectores son antiparalelos")
        else:
            print("Los vectores son paralelos")
    else:
        print("Los vectores no son paralelos")
```

Aquí se tienen en cuenta otras condiciones para poder aplicar este criterio, como por ejemplo:

1. Que si los dos vectores (listas) tienen diferente longitud no se podrán comparar.
2. Que el vector nulo ([0],[0,0],[0,0,0],...) es paralelo a todo vector de su misma dimensión.
3. Si los vectores son proporcionales pero con una proporción negativa, se dice que son "antiparalelos".